# RDS License Needed clarification

Tags: windows

just want to know want do I need to license with RDS CAL based on the work flow below. We have this Server A where users connect to it to select the application they want to access by login their credentials. Once the users was approved on Server A it will communicate with Server B (where application
and RDSH also installed) to server the application needed by the user. Server A uses it's own account when communicating with RDSH server. My question is do I need RDS User CAL for those users or just the RDS Device CAL is enough?